# Windows 10 universal app round button with 'animation' when clicked

Tags: xaml, user-interface, win-universal-app

I am currently trying to create a simple button in the shape of a circle that reacts int eh same way the default button does to a click (you can visually see a reaction when clicking on a default button, the color changes among other things).

I have made a circular button using the Ellipse attribute. This removed any reaction (in terms of visuals) the button had to a click. 
In an attempt to bring it back I used the visual manager. 
My issue is that I cannot combine the two successfully.

How should I go about doing this?

Is there perhaps a simpler way to make a round button that reacts to clicks?

Ideally I would like something that does this with code and avoid the use of Blend which I have seen mentioned in several places.

Below are the two code snippets in XAML.

Just a simple round button:

```
<Button Name="bottomCircle" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Fill="Blue">
                </Ellipse>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

A button with "animation":

```
<Button Content="Click Me" x:Name="ClickMe" Background="Blue" Grid.Row="2"  Width="100" Height="100" >
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedHighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" /> 
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames> 
                            </Storyboard> 
                        </VisualState> 
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Border x:Name="PressedHighlightBackground" Background="Transparent">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `CornerRadius` of your border elements to some large number, you'll get a circle:

```
<Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        CornerRadius="100" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <Border x:Name="PressedHighlightBackground" Background="Transparent"
            CornerRadius="100">
        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

(I do believe you can get away with just a single `Border` element, though.)

Also, using `Storyboard` and `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` is cumbersome. You can use `VisualState.Setters` instead, which is easier to maintain.

To react to clicks and moseovers **only** within the circle, remove the outer `Grid`, which doesn't provide anything anyway. In addition, be advised that the visual state `MouseOver` works better if you rename it `PointerOver`.

This works the way you want:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="Click Me" x:Name="ClickMe" Background="Blue" Grid.Row="2"  Width="100" Height="100" Foreground="White">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border
                    x:Name="ButtonBackground"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="100" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Border
                        x:Name="PressedHighlightBackground"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        CornerRadius="100">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter
                                        Target="ContentContainer.Foreground"
                                        Value="Pink" />
                                    <Setter
                                        Target="PressedHighlightBackground.Background"
                                        Value="Blue" />
                                    <Setter
                                        Target="ButtonBackground.BorderBrush"
                                        Value="{StaticResource AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter
                                        Target="ContentContainer.Foreground"
                                        Value="Black" />
                                    <Setter
                                        Target="PressedHighlightBackground.Background"
                                        Value="{StaticResource AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    <Setter
                                        Target="ButtonBackground.BorderBrush"
                                        Value="{StaticResource AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This seems promising, thank you. Good to see that there is way to round out the button without using the Ellipse method. 

Unfortunately this button still reacts when clicking outside of the circle but still within the square (what the button would have been without rounded corners). 
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I'm sure it's fixable; I'll think it over. In the meantime, if this works for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite cut it. I will definitely up-vote it though, it's a good thing to know and solves the problem halfway.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.